# SQL Stored Procedure Error converting data type varchar to bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and I have a Stored Procedure.  The final part where I am receiving the above error is this part:

```
Set @SQL = '
Select Style=case when AttNr = 2 then '''' else Entity end'+@SQL+' 
 From  #Temp 
 Where Entity not in (Select Entity From #Temp Where AttNr=2 Group By Entity Having Sum(cast(Value as bigint))=0) 
 Group By Entity,AttNr 
 Order By Entity,AttNr
'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Updated to:

```
Set @SQL = '
Select Style=case when AttNr = 2 then '''' else Entity end'+@SQL+' 
 From  #Temp 
 Where Entity not in (Select cast(Entity as varchar(100)) From #Temp Where AttNr=2 Group By Entity Having Sum(cast(Value as bigint))=0) 
 Group By Entity,AttNr 
 Order By Entity,AttNr
'
```

I must be doing something stupid - changed to:

```
Set @SQL = '
Select Style=case when AttNr = ''2'' then '''' else Entity end'+@SQL+' 
 From  #Temp 
 Where Entity not in (Select cast(Entity as varchar(100)) From #Temp Where AttNr=2 Group By Entity Having Sum(cast(Value as bigint))=0) 
 Group By Entity,AttNr 
 Order By Entity,AttNr
'
```

Ok, I changed to the below:

```
Set @SQL = '
Select Style=case when AttNr = ''2'' then '''' else cast(Entity as varchar(100)) end'+@SQL+' 
 From  #Temp 
 Where Entity not in (Select cast(Entity as varchar(100)) From #Temp Where AttNr=''2'' Group By Entity Having Sum(cast(Value as bigint))=0) 
 Group By Entity,AttNr 
 Order By Entity,AttNr
'
```

But still a no go - same error.

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: Do you have any data in there that will not convert (ie, not numbers)?

Comment: When you store numeric data in a varchar column.

Comment: cast the else entity part to varchar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

maybe your data is null and it cannot cast to bigint ....
just replace this piece of code in your query ...

```
SUM((CAST(ISNULL(Value , '0') as bigint)))
```

do it for any null value that should cast ...

Answer (score 1):

do

```
cast(Entity as varchar(100))
```

You are getting the error because Case follows data type precedence .so values in Then  and Else will be converted to same data type which has higher precedence

Example below:

```
Declare @a int=1
select case when @A=1 then '''' else cast(@a as varchar(10)) end
```

Error:
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ''' to data type int.

It is also possible ,that AttNr has some varchar values,so try casting to varchar implicitly,if this is the case..

`AttNr ='2`'